# Api blueprint query and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have in blueprint this kind of GET query:

```
/user?{firstName,lastName}
```

and I'm not sure what does it mean. Is this optional parameters? And how should url looks like in angular because with this:

```
url: 'http://localhost:4000/user?Arnold&Schwarz';
```

doesn't work (in postman works fine)

Comment: Maybe it's supposed to be `http://localhost:4000/user?firstName=Arnold&lastName=Schwarz`.

Comment: It also doesn't work

Comment: Well, there's no way for us to _know_ what would work, we can just guess. You'll have to ask the person that defined `/user?{firstName,lastName}` what a proper URL would be.